# The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i am using asp.net core 3.1 this code in used for saving data into database and iIt works fine until i add the code for search it gives this error (The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:)

this is the controller

```
namespace Info.Controllers
{
    public class DemoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public DemoController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = _context.Files.ToList();
            return View(result);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(IFormFile files)
        {
            if (files != null)
            {
                if (files.Length > 0)
                {
                    //Getting FileName
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                    //Getting file Extension
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    // concatenating  FileName + FileExtension
                    //var newFileName = String.Concat(Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()), fileExtension);
                    var newFileName = String.Concat((Guid.NewGuid()), fileExtension);

                    var objfiles = new Files()
                    {
                        DocumentId = 0,
                        Name = newFileName,
                        FileType = fileExtension,
                    };

                    using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        files.CopyTo(target);
                        objfiles.DataFiles = target.ToArray();
                    }

                    _context.Files.Add(objfiles);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
                        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadImage(string filename,int id)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename is not availble");
            var file = await _context.Files.Where(x => x.DocumentId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename);
            var memory = new MemoryStream();           
            {              
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            var types = GetMimeTypes();
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return types[ext];
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {".txt", "text/plain"},
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".gif", "image/gif"},
                {".csv", "text/csv"}
            };
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
        {
            var FileController = from m in _context.Files
                                 select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                FileController = FileController.Where(s => s.Name!.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(await FileController.ToListAsync());
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried modifying the code for search but to no avail

Comment: You either need to provide a different Route or a different Verb for the two actions.

Comment: you have two Index action method using `[HttpPost]` attribute. most probably this causes the multiple endpoint error. method signiture is diffirent but i guess it must be one action method marked with the same httpattribute.

Comment: Could you please share your view for `Index(string searchString)`. It seems that something wrong in view while sending request. Would be great if you could include your view into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your search be a `HttpGet`? if both functions are `HttpPost` how will it know which one to call?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using asp.net core 3.1 this code in used for saving data into
> database and iIt works fine until i add the code for search it gives
> this error (The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:)

Well, your exceprtion is pretty obvious. Because in `asp.net core` regardless of its version deosn't accept same action name with same `HTTP VERB` consequently you are getting the exception. You have following action ambiguity

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(IFormFile files) 
        //Should Rename To Create
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString) 
       //Should Rename to Search
```

I am hoping you got following error:

**Exception Reproduced:**

[image]

**Solution:**

It can be resolved in many ways, for instance, you can rename your controller action, you can modify the HTTP Verb. If you just rename your `public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)` to `Search` instead of `Index` or modify the http verb from `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]` your issue would be resolved.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** You should always keep in mind while define a name for your [controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-7.0#defining-actions), [action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-7.0#defining-actions), [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-7.0#defining-actions), or variable for the sake of readability.

```
* Index - the main "landing" page. This is also the default endpoint.
* Edit - an edit page for the "thing"
* New - a create page for the "thing"
* Create - creates a new "thing" (and saves it if you're using a DB)
* Search- While searching from list or anything.
```

You can have look on naming convensions guidelines for [asp.net core here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have changed as requested and when i press the search key no change has occurred

Comment: Could you please share how you are sending request? Does it hit your ccontroller? What do you mean my no change occured? Please share more details.

Comment: this is my controller for search    [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string searchname)
        {
            var FileController = from m in _context.Files
                                 select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchname))
            {
                FileController = FileController.Where(s => s.Name!.Contains(searchname));
            }

            return View(await FileController.ToListAsync());
        }This means that the page is displayed without any error messages, and when pressing the search key, no change occurs

Comment: @model List<Info.Models.Files>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<form asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="Index">
    <p>
        Title: <input type="text" name="searchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>